# php check if array has subarray not working

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, foreach

I am trying to check if `array` has `subarray` or not. But it doesn't work. For example, though It is checked `main` which has `subarray`, it echo, `it hasn't submenu` What is wrong here ?

```
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="main">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="menu[0][]" value="sub-main1"></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="menu[0][]" value="sub-main2"></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="menu[0][]" value="sub-main3"></li>
     </ul>
</li>

<li><input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="sport"></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="art"></li>
```

PHP

```
foreach ($_POST["menu"] AS $key => $item){
    if (is_array($item)){
        echo "It has submenu";
    }
    else{
        echo "it hasn't submenu";
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by checking the results of `var_dump($_POST["menu"])` to make sure you are getting what you expect.

Comment: @Mr Glass I did already-var_dump($_POST["menu"]), it prints accurate array . I'm asking about what is problem in nested array.

Comment: please post the results of the var_dump. I see no obvious issue with the PHP so examining the data would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It works while changing

```
if (is_array($item)){
```

to

```
if(is_array($_POST["menu"][$key])){
```